# How to skip empty record in Tilemill teaser so label doesn't show '0'

Tags: mustache, mapbox, tilemill

In Tilemill teaser, I want to show 5 fields such as:

```
{{{Subvendor Name}}}<br> 
{{{MBE}}}<br> 
{{{SBE}}}<br> 
{{{WBE}}}<br> 
{{{DBE}}}<br> 
{{{SDB}}}<br> 
{{{DVE}}}<br> 
{{{HUB}}}
```

Some fields have information while others will be blank, depending on the record.
How do I make it so only fields with information are displayed in teaser?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the manual of the [Mustache Template Engine](https://mustache.github.io). In the [manual](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) under *Non-Empty Lists* and following.

For example if you want to output the code for `SDB`

```
{{#SDB}}
  <h3>Value for SDB:</h3>
  <p>{{SDB}}</p>
{{/SDB}}
```

The whole `h3/p`-block will only be printed if `{{{SDB}}}` is not empty/false. Which in your case translates to:

```
{{{#Subvendor Name}}}
  {{{Subvendor Name}}}<br/>
{{{/Subvendor Name}}}
…
```

Comment: @user4015 was this of any help to you?